# Resolving unforeseen view matter for calling function from view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having some real difficult resolving an issue. Basically I person will search for a room and I will display a list (including pagination) of rooms matching the criteria. Now the issue arises when I try to call for the room's image. The first image will display but the rest wont, I get the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: views/search_view.php
>
> Line Number: 27
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/search_view.php
>
> Line Number: 27

This is what I have done so far

My Model:

```
function get_room_image($rid)
{
    $q = $this->db
        ->where('room_id',$rid)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('room_image');

    return $q->result();

}

function search_rooms() 
{
    $q = $this->db
        ->where('features', $this->input->post('features'))
        ->get('rooms');

    $room['results'] = $q->result();

    return $room['results'];
}
```

My Controller:

```
function search()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'search_view';
    $data['page_title'] = 'Search';

    $data['results'] = $this->site_model->search_rooms();

    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}
```

My View:

```
...    
<?php foreach ($results['results'] as $room) { 

    $room_images = $this->site_model->get_room_image($room->id); ?>
        <div class="col2 bot">

            <div class="col_head"></div>
                <div class="col_info">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                <tr><td> 
                <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'room/' . $room_images[0]->image_name; ?>" border="0" class="imgbox" />
                </td> 
...
```

Line 27 is actually the line with the img tag on it

When I do a var_dump as requested I get the following:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["room_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["image_name"]=>
    string(36) "1614d828817ac5b396660621048b167a.jpg"
  }
}

array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
...
```

SO it seems that it isn't performing the get_room_image function on each iteration correctly

Any advice is most welcome.

Regards,

Comment: try doing a var_dump($room_images) on that line - see what is actually there. I'm guessing the index of [0] is wrong for some of the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved as I forgot to add a ";" onto a line within my db query string

Answer (score 3):

First,I don't think that you should be calling the model from within the view. You should call the model from within the controller and pass it to your view. Another SO post that talks about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733309/1260593

You should try to perform a join on the tables in your model.

Model:

```
function search_rooms() 
{
$q =  $this->db
 ->select('*')
 ->from('rooms')
 ->where('features', $this->input->post('features'))
 ->join('room_image', 'rooms.id = room_image.room_id');

return $q;
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'search_view';
$data['page_title'] = 'Search';

$data['results'] = $this->site_model->search_rooms();

$this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($results->result() as $room) { 

   $image = $room->image_name;
    <div class="col2 bot">

        <div class="col_head"></div>
            <div class="col_info">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr><td> 
            <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'room/' . $image; ?>" border="0" class="imgbox" />
            </td> 
}
```

Comment: when turn $room_images[0]->image_name to $room_images->image_name I get the error: Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Did you try the join query or you were able to fix your code by adding the ";"?